# Importing Vue app into Chrome extension content script

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vue-component

I have a Chrome extension I made with Vue that uses Vue in the popup. I want to take the popup vue app and move it to the content script now, so when the user presses the icon the app shows up in the page content. Given that the content script can't call external js, how is this accomplished? I've previously seen Chrome extensions that use Vue / React / etc. in the content.

Comment: In the content script add an iframe to the page and point it to chrome.runtime.getURL('popup.html'). The file should be exposed in web_accessible_resources.